# JSP Passing value from one page to another

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I'm trying to pass all the value from A page to B page, but once I submit form from B page  it will link to A page in the pop up window screen. Which mean it will have 2 windows show A page, one is in normal window another 1 is in pop up window.

Here are the sample of the code how they works.

### FILE A.jsp

```
<%
 String NAME_1=  common.setNullToString(request.getParameter("NAME_1")); 
 String ETYPE =  common.setNullToString(request.getParameter("ETYPE")); 
%>
<script language="Javascript">
function fnExtra()
{
var cntype = document.mainform.CNTYPE.value;
window.open("b.jsp?TYPE="+cntype);
}
</script>
<body>
<form method="post" type="test.jsp">
<Table>
    <tr>
       <td>
        <select name="CNTYPE">
           <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
           <option value="E01">Apple </option>
           <option value="E02">Orange</option>
        <select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name : 
         <%if(ETYPE.equals("E01")){%>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<%=NAME%>">
         <%}else{%>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<%=NAME_1%>">
         <%}%>
        <a href="Javascript:fnExtra();">Change</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

In file A.jsp when i click on the "link" it will pop up a window for B.jsp

### FILE B.jsp

```
<% 
   String NAME 1= "";
   String ETYPE = common.setNullToString(request.getParameter("TYPE")); 
%>
<form name="mainform" method="post" action="A.jsp?ETYPE=<%=ETYPE%>">
<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Name :</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="NAME_1" id="NAME_1" value="<%=NAME_1%>" >
        </td>
    </tr>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" >             
 </table>
</form>
```

What i aiming for is, when i click submit on submit button in B.jsp, the pop up screen B.jsp will close and all the value in B.jsp will replace A.jsp value based on the condition.

Comment: I try put onSubmit="window.close()" in b.jsp, the pop up screen will close. But in A.jsp the value is not replaced.

Comment: Did you notice `type="javascript>`?

Comment: Sorry, code Edited. wrong type.

Comment: Okay. Next, you will need to programmatically send the values to `A` using javascript (since you are aborting the form submission). Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.parent).

Comment: Same, A page value is not replaced, hmm ... i remove form action and onSubmit, added this function `onclick="visitPage();` in B page button and javascript function `function visitPage()
{
var A = document.mainform.NAME_1.value;
var B = "<%=ETYPE%>";
 window.parent.location.href = "A.jsp?NAME_1="+A+"&ETYPE="+B;
 window.close();
}`

Comment: No. That's not what you want either. I think you want something like `window.parent.document.getElementByName('name').value = blah;`

Comment: hmmm.. i tried this yet still the same ..
`var A = document.mainform.NAME_1.value;
window.parent.document.getElementsByName("name").value= A;
window.close();`

Comment: Use the javascript debugger tools. Press F-12.